# Comparing items in list and replace, if needed

Tags: java

I have some misunderstanding regarding how to compare current item in List with next item and replace item by using new value.

I have got some code, but it doesn't work correctly.

```
final List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
items.add("1");
items.add("2");
items.add("3");
items.add("4");
items.add("5");
items.add("6");

public List<String> replaceItems(final List<String> oldList) {
    final List<String> replacedItems = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < oldList.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < oldList.size(); j++) {
            if (oldList.get(i).equals(oldList.get(j)) {
               replacedItems.add("replaced");
            } else if (StringUtils.isAnyBlank(oldList.get(i), oldList.get(j))) {
              replacedItems.add("empty");
             }
            replacedItems.add("new value");
        }
      }
   }
}
```

There is some bug in my code. Because 'replacedItems' list should have size == 5, but current size of the 'replacedItems' is 45. Help me to solve this issue please. I need to get replacedItems list with the same size as of oldList.

Comment: You are iterating all the combinations of two items, not just current with next. Also, totally unclear what that code is supposed to do and how it related to your example list.

Comment: tobias_k, can you help me by adding some marks to my part of code please ?

Comment: My code shoud do following:

Comment: My code shoud do following:

1. Iterate through the oldList and looking for duplicates. If duplicates are found -> replase duplicate by adding new value (e.q "replased value")

2. if duplicates are not found -> replase curent item from 'old list' by adding new value (e.q "new value")

Comment: Your example doesn't compile. The parentheses don't balance, and your method has no return statement. When I make the obvious changes necessary to compile, it returns a list of length 15, not 45.

Comment: Note - once you've made it compile, if you amend `replacedItems.add("new value")` to `replacedItems.add("new value " + i + ", " + j)` -- then output the list contents, you'll see clearly where the 15 entries come from.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of size:

You add values in the second (nested) loop which will execute insertion in every iteration. Use your inner loop to determine that your current value (oldList.get(i)) what type (new, empty, duplicated) is. You can achieve this with some kind of flag. After that you should make one insertion after the inner loop but still inside the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you iterate all the combinations of items and add a new item like `replaced` or `new value` for each such combination. Instead, you could use a flag `already_seen`, set it to `true` if you find a duplicate, and only add the new element *after* the inner loop. However, this will still have quadratic complexity. Instead, I'd suggest you just use a `Set` of already seen elements. You can use `! add` to simultaneously add the item and see whether it was already present in the set. Also, you probably only want to check whether the current item is blank, not any item in any of the combinations.

```
public List<String> replaceItems(List<String> oldList) {
    Set<String> seenItems = new HashSet<>();
    List<String> replacedItems = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String item : oldList) {
        if (! seenItems.add(item)) {
            replacedItems.add("replaced");
        } else if (item.isEmpty()) {
            replacedItems.add("empty");
        } else {
            replacedItems.add("new value");
        }
    }
    return replacedItems;
}
```

Example:

```
List<String> items = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "2", "", "5", "5");
System.out.println(replaceItems(items));
// [new value, new value, replaced, empty, new value, replaced]
```

Answer (score 0):

The program you wrote does not have a well thought approach. You must first think about the steps which should be written in the program. Here are the steps:

Assuming that oldList and items are present as you intend

**Step 1** - pick the one value at a time(as you did). Refer it with i (as you did)

**Step 2** - compare with all the array elements, including the one in step 1 (you excluded items before element i). Refer it as j (as you did)

**Step 3** - check that if i and j are not equal but oldList[i] and oldList[j] are equal, set dupFound to true (initialize it with false just above step 2)

**Step 4** - just after the inner loop, check that the value is not empty and dupfound and set your values here.

I have done some modification to your code and added dupFound to your code. Try to debug and fix if there are any issues.

```
    final List<String> replacedItems = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < oldList.size(); i++) {
        boolean dupFound = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < oldList.size(); j++) {
            if (i != j){
                if (oldList.get(i).equals(oldList.get(j))) {
                    dupFound = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (dupFound) {
            replacedItems.add("replaced");
        } else if (StringUtils.isEmpty(oldList.get(i))) {
            replacedItems.add("empty");
        } else {
            replacedItems.add("new value");
        }
    }
```

Just one more note, the above algorithm assumes that if a number exists more than once, all it's values will be displayed as replaced. If you want the first to be marked as new value, the above algorithm will have to be changed to:

**Step 1** - pick the one value at a time(as you did). Refer it with i (as you did)

**Step 2** - check if the value is present in the array between element 0 to i-1. If yes set boolean newVal to false (initialize it with true just above step 2)

**Step 3** - if oldList[i] is empty, add empty else if newVal is true, add "new value" to array else add replaced

here is the modified version to implement this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < oldList.size(); i++) {
        boolean newVal = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++){
            if (oldList.get(i).equals(oldList.get(j))){
                newVal = false;
            }
        }

        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(oldList.get(i))){
            replacedItems.add("empty");
        } else if (newVal) {
            replacedItems.add("new value");
        } else {
            replacedItems.add("replaced");
        }

    }
```

Feel free to play around with the arrays a bit and try to write it first as an algorithm. Trust me it helps.